# HTML page doesn't scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

My webpage doesn't scroll! I do not know why this problem arise!
The page: http://devlobby.tech/fivem/lua/

In the main file, I included 2 others php files:

```
<?php
    include '../../include/menu.php';
    include '../../include/layout.php';
?>
```

I provided 3 links of 3 php files:
The main index.php: https://pastebin.com/c27dEi4e
Menu file - menu.php: https://pastebin.com/AYy0AY00
Layout file - layout.php: https://pastebin.com/h0swdiMf

Comment: IT's sound like why this code is not working.... probably the content of the page doesn't need to scroll... you have to do some debug to your code

Comment: It should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting your code with browser console i have found you have set `overflow hidden` in your css code:

```
body, html { 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;//remove
}
```

Remove `overflow hidden` and it will work

[image: here is hte overflow hidden]